# Macbook bluetooth connection with my earphone

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, high-sierra, ear-phones

suddenly my macbook air (High Sierra OS) starts to have problems with my earphones bluetooth.
After few minutes that I'm connected to my earphones, they start to make a scretch sound and after a while my macbook lose the connectivity with them. Sometimes happens that the laptop can't reproduce any sound with the earphones. 
I've already tried with another mac and the earphones works correctly, I have this problem just with my mac.
I've already cancel my earphone from the bluetooth devices list and pair them again, but it didn't solve anything.

Anyone than can help me?
Thank you very much!
Cheers

Comment: could you provide what bt earphones you are using and specs for your mac?

Comment: Actually I've just solve the problem, it was a NVRAM problem, by resetting it the problem has been solved. Thank you very much for the help anyway!

Comment: Cool, then please add an answer to the post with instructions on how to reset it, and accept it. Then others running into the same problem can find and use your solution!

Answer (score 1):

I'm copying here the link of how to reset the NVRAM, this is how I've fix my problem:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063
I hope that it'll help someone else! :)

Cheers!